# React Native - Can I strip off .so files contained in Android lib folder in release build in Android?

Tags: android, react-native, build, compression, apk

I am working on a `React Native` App for which I want to decrease the build size, Currently, It's going above 45Mb (The Universal build)

If the split individual then also above 14.

After analyzing the APK, I found `.so files` contained in `lib` took 77% of the total APK size.

I am not sure if they are actually required in release builds. If not needed how can I strip them to optimize my build size?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are the files of the libraries that you are using in your app, if there are some libs that you don't use you can just uninstall them, but removing .so files will break your app